# Abrir un enlace externo a un fichero que tiene espacios en el nombre

Tags: html, python, pyqt5, pyqt

Estoy haciendo una App en Python y en algunas partes del programa informo al usuario que se han creado varios documentos, y esto lo muestro en un widget `QTextBrowser()`.
Yo lo muestro con un hipervinculo para que de esa forma al hacer click en el, al usuario se le abra el fichero.
He conseguido que funcione si el fichero no tiene espacios en blanco en su ruta.

He leído en muchos foros pero no encuentro la solución.

He escrito estos dos códigos para hacer pruebas.

En el código 1 utilizo `QLabel` y funciona perfectamente, pero si uso `QTextBrowser` no funciona.

Opción 1 funciona porque no hay espacios en la ruta del fichero.

Opción 7 y 10, abren el fichero pero el contenido se vuelca dentro del wiget.

Alguna idea?

CODE 1

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextBrowser,QTextEdit,QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
label=QLabel()
file_2='c:/temp/test 2/test.docx'
urlLink="<a href='file:///%s'>'Opción_12'</a>"%(file_2)
label.setText(urlLink)
label.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
label.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

CODE 2

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextBrowser,QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    text_area = QTextBrowser()
    file='c:/temp/test.docx'
    link='<a href='"'{}'"'>Opción_1</a>'.format(file)
    text_area.insertHtml(link)
    
    
    file_2='c:/temp/test 2/test.docx'
    link='<br><a href='"'{}'"'>Opción_2</a></br>'.format(file_2)
    text_area.insertHtml(link)

    file_2_reformated=file_2.replace(" ", "\\ ")
    link='<br><a href='"'{}'"'>Opción_3</a></br>'.format(file_2_reformated)
    text_area.insertHtml(link)

    file_2_reformated=file_2.replace(" ", "%20")
    link='<br><a href='"'{}'"'>Opción_4</a></br>'.format(file_2_reformated)
    text_area.insertHtml(link)

    file_2_reformated=chr(34)+file_2+chr(34)
    link='<br><a href='"'{}'"'>Opción_5</a></br>'.format(file_2_reformated)
    text_area.insertHtml(link)

    file_2_reformated = " \"" + file_2 + " \""
    link='<br><a href='"'{}'"'>Opción_6</a></br>'.format(file_2_reformated)
    text_area.insertHtml(link)

    link='<br><a href='"'file:///{}'"'>Opción_7</a></br>'.format(file_2)
    text_area.insertHtml(link)

    link='<br><a href='"'https://{}'"'>Opción_8</a></br>'.format(file_2)
    text_area.insertHtml(link)

    file_3="file:///c:/temp/test 2/test.docx"
    link='<br><a href='"'https://{}'"'>Opción_9</a></br>'.format(file_3.as_uri())
    text_area.insertHtml(link)

    file_2='c:/temp/test 2/test.docx'
    link = '<br><a href="{}">Opción_10</a></br>'.format(QUrl.fromLocalFile(file_2).toString())
    text_area.insertHtml(link)

    file_2='c:/temp/test 2/test.docx'
    link = '<br><a href="\'{}\'">Opción_11</a></br>'.format(QUrl.fromLocalFile(file_2).toString())
    text_area.insertHtml(link)

    from pathlib import PureWindowsPath

    file_3 = PureWindowsPath("c:/temp/test 2/test.docx")
    link = '<br><a href="{}">Opción_13</a></br>'.format(file_3.as_uri())
    text_area.insertHtml(link)
    
    text_area.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
    text_area.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice la pregunta también en StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65909349/open-external-link-file-with-blank-space

Y aquí está la solución que hace que funcionen 3 de las opciones incluida la de ChemaCortes:

Aquí está el código por si es de utilidad:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextBrowser
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDesktopServices
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    text_area = QTextBrowser()
    text_area.setOpenLinks(False)

    def handle_links(url):
        if not url.scheme():
            url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(url.toString())
        QDesktopServices.openUrl(url)

    text_area.anchorClicked.connect(handle_links)

    file='c:/temp/test.docx'
    link='<a href='"'{}'"'>Opción_1</a>'.format(file)
    text_area.insertHtml(link)   

    file_2='c:/temp/test 2/test.docx'    
    link='<br><a href='"'file:///{}'"'>Opción_7</a></br>'.format(file_2)
    text_area.insertHtml(link)

    link = '<br><a href="{}">Opción_10</a></br>'.format(QUrl.fromLocalFile(file_2).toString())
    text_area.insertHtml(link)

    from pathlib import PureWindowsPath

    file_3 = PureWindowsPath("c:/temp/test 2/test.docx")
    link = '<br><a href="{}">Opción_13</a></br>'.format(file_3.as_uri())
    text_area.insertHtml(link)

    text_area.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que cambiar los espacios por `%20`, que es lo recomendable con urls. Una forma de hacerlo es usando la función `urllib.parse.quote`. Pero lo que te recomiendo es que,  siempre que necesites manipular rutas de ficheros, uses el módulo `pathlib`.

Por ejemplo:

```py
from pathlib import PureWindowsPath

fichero = PureWindowsPath("c:/temp/test 2/test.docx")

print(fichero.as_uri())
```

Resultado:

```
'file:///c:/temp/test%202/test.docx'
```

PD: no sé porqué la *opción 7* te vuelca el contenido, aunque no estoy seguro cuál es de todas en concreto.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, he probado tu solución y no me funciona. Lo he actualizado en mi código como opción 13.

Comment: Te has dejado el `.as_uri()`

Comment: Ostras tienes razón, disculpa. Lo he probado como me indicas y sigue sin funcionar (lo he actualizado en el código).

Comment: ¿Y has probado a quitar las comillas que sobran? `'<br><a href="{}">Opción_13</a></br>'.format(...`

Comment: Si lo he hecho (y actualizado código en pregunta), y el fichero se consigue abrir, pero el contenido se vuelva dentro del widget. Que es lo que me pasa en las opciones 7 y 10. Esto es muy extraño de verdad, porque si en lugar de ser un QTextBrowser es un QLabel entonces funciona (opción 12).

Comment: Entonces estamos hablando de otra cosa. El widget que usas no es capaz de abrir rutas de ficheros, sólo mostrar html. Desconozco qt para indicarte alguna solución.

Comment: Chema muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Efectivamente debe ser una especificidad del QT. Abrí otro hilo en stackoverflow y me dieron la solución aprendiendo algo nuevo que no sabia.